# Send notifications with php

Tags: php, android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I want to send notifications to my phone with php.

I have stored the register id in a database when the user (in this case: me) connects like this in Android:

```
nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("regid", GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(c).register(SENDER_ID)));
if (nvp != null) {
  httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
}
```

where nvp is a `List<NameValuePair>` and `SENDER_ID` my project identifier on Google

Then I have a script in Php "sendnotifs.php" like this:

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>GCM Demo application</title>
</head>
<body>
 <?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
   $connexion = mysqli_connect("localhost:3306", "root", "password", "alo") or die(mysqli_error());

   if(!$connexion){die('MySQL connection failed');}

   $regid = "\n";
   echo $regid;
   $sql = "SELECT regid FROM personne WHERE id=27";
   $result = mysqli_query($connexion,$sql);
   $regid = array();
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    array_push($regid, $row['regid']);
   }

   // Set POST variables
         $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $message = array("Notice" => $_POST['message']);
         $fields = array(
             'registration_ids' => $regid,
             'data' => $message,
         );

         $headers = array(
             'Authorization: key=Mykey',
             'Content-Type: application/json'
         );
         // Open connection
         $ch = curl_init();

         // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

         // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

         curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

         // Execute post
         $result = curl_exec($ch);
         if ($result === FALSE) {
             die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
         }

         // Close connection
         curl_close($ch);
         echo $result;
  }

 ?>
 <form method="post" action="sendnotifs.php">
  <label>Insert Message: </label><input type="text" name="message" />

  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" />
 </form>
</body>
</html>
```

where `$regid`is the register id end `id=27` is my identifier

I have registered my phone by downloading AL-GMC Client and clicking "Register Device for GCM"

And I've wroten class to receive the notifications

```
public class Objet_GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                Objet_GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
    }
}
```

And this one:

```
public class Objet_GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
    public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private static final String TAG = "GcmIntentService";
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

    public Objet_GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (!extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            /*
             * Filter messages based on message type. Since it is likely that GCM
             * will be extended in the future with new message types, just ignore
             * any message types you're not interested in, or that you don't
             * recognize.
             */
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Send error: " + extras.toString());
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
                sendNotification("Deleted messages on server: " +
                        extras.toString());
                // If it's a regular GCM message, do some work.
            } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                    MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                // This loop represents the service doing some work.
                for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Working... " + (i+1)
                            + "/5 @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(5000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
                Log.i(TAG, "Completed work @ " + SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
                // Post notification of received message.
                sendNotification(extras.getString("Notice"));
                Log.i(TAG, "Received: " + extras.toString());
            }
        }
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        Objet_GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    // Put the message into a notification and post it.
    // This is just one simple example of what you might choose to do with
    // a GCM message.
    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
                this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, Activite_AssistantLevel0.class), 0);

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                        // .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_gcm)
                        .setContentTitle("GCMDemo")
                        .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.logo)
                        .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                                .bigText(msg))
                        .setContentText(msg);

        mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

But it doesn't work...

Where I try to send "I am a fool" on my "sendnotifs.php" page with Google Chrome,I have this kind of return, without notification on my phone...:

```
{"multicast_id":5009376049877517345,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1440530144017191%e7498dd9f9fd7ecd"}]}
```

or this one without notifications neither...:

```
{"multicast_id":7798455372304463190,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"NotRegistered"}]}
```

Does someone know what I've missed?
Thanks for your future answers ;)

Comment: any oauth authentication for your service is required ?

Comment: No, there is not. I have not a website yet! It's only the android application which I am developping. It's not yet on the Google Play market. And I use it by usb between my phone and Android Studio

Comment: so you are trying to access local ip with your android app ?

Comment: Yes exactly. All my php scripts are based on local adress adress like http://myip/sendnotifs.php for the one which I asked about!

Comment: well with a ddms or any context execution monitoring tools that available you are not able to make connections with your local ip

Comment: Ah ok so do you say that I have to put my App on Google Play, MySQL database on a distant distant to be able to sens notifications? There are not others ways to test locally before?

Comment: well i dont know any . but you can find free server on heroku.com to make your app online

Comment: OK thanks. I will do that. After the all others parts will be finished.:)